# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuote() when customer clicks “review your information” using Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: magento, paypal

Magento is returning Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuote() on a non-object in/home/discoun1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php when customer click continue button on paypal “review your information”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be a problem with your custom theme.

Try this:

1. get the paypal folder from
   app/design/frontend/base/default/template;
2. get paypal.xml from app/design/frontend/base/default/layout;
3. copy the paypal folder above to
   app/design/frontend/default/[yourthemename]/template
4. copy the XML above to app/design/frontend/default/[yourthemename]/layout

This should update the paypal files to your theme.

Comment: Humm. My template doesn't have theses folder. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Eiii I've had this problem too, and this worked for me too.

In my case I'd overwritten 3 files of the Paypal folder in my template, so I already have the folder and the xml in my templates default folder. In spite of the review showed me a blank page, but with your solution the reviwe page works fine.

I don't understand why Magento does not find the rest of the files from core. Could you give me a explantion of that.

Good job. :)